# theme_suggestions_html_alter not being picked

Tags: hooks, theming

I'm trying to implement a custom template html--front--anonymous.html.twig which replaces html.html.twig. The suggestion is being showed, but its file is not being picked.

my_theme.theme

```
function MY_THEME_theme_suggestions_html_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) { 
        if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
            $suggestions[] = 'html--front--anonymous';
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: Screenshot that shows theme suggestions for html.html.twig]
[image: Screenshot that shows the content of the folder layout, which contains html.html.twig and others]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions need to use underscores rather than dashes:

```
$suggestions[] = 'html__front__anonymous';
```

Comment: I had tried that, but setting underscores in the filename too, which didn't work. Now I understand that the declaration of the suggestion must be with underscores, but the filename must be with dashes.